# How to compute $L_{\rm eq}$ from temporal pressure data

Tags: acoustics, frequency, data-analysis

I have pressure vs time data. how can I compute sound equivalence Level $L_{\rm eq}$ in decibels? can this be done from a frequency spectrum assuming that it is constant?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this website](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/equivalent-sound-level-d_721.html), sound equivalence level is defined as

$$L_{eq} = 10 \log{\left( \frac{1}{p_{ref}^2} \frac{\int_0 ^T p_A(t)^2 dt}{T} \right)}$$

where $p_{ref}$ is a reference pressure (usually $20 \times 10^{-6} \text{ Pa}$), $p_A(t)$ is sound pressure, and $T$ is the time period of integration.

Given a frequency spectrum, you could use the inverse Fourier Transform to find the pressure as a function of time.

Comment: Exactly, we should keep in mind that Leq is a "time-domain" quantity. If the Leq in some frequency band is required, the signal should be filtered and then compute the quantity. If FFT is used, the Leq for the corresponding frequency band of the specific frequency bin can be computed. From [Parseval's theorme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem), both should be equivalent. More information about the Leq can be found in ISOs such as [ISO 1996-2:2007, Acoustics - Description, Measurement and Assessment of Environmental Noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem).